# query ipaddresses by subnet

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a MS SQLServer 2005 table which includes an ipaddress column, and I would like to count entries by subnet.

Unfortunately the ipaddress column is a varchar with sample data like:
192.168.10.20
10.1.2.3

I think the best approach would be to convert the ipaddress to an integer, and then I could apply the appropriate bitmask.

Are there any suggestions on how to get a string of 4 octets into an integer?

Answer (score 1):

To convert a 4 octtet dotted notation to a BIGINT we can do the following.

DECLARE @IP CHAR(15) SET @IP='192.168.123.123'

select (CONVERT(BIGINT, PARSENAME(@IP,1)) +
     CONVERT(BIGINT, PARSENAME(@IP,2)) * 256 +
     CONVERT(BIGINT, PARSENAME(@IP,3)) * 65536 +
     CONVERT(BIGINT, PARSENAME(@IP,4)) * 16777216)

from there it's a pretty simple thing to AND that with 4294967040 (255.255.255.0) to get /24 subnet

Thanks to [Less Than Dot](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/how-to-convert-ip-addresses-between-bigi) for the code.

Answer (score 0):

you could also do this by using PARSENAME function as it is show [here](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-the-parsename-function-to-split-delimited-data).